# how to fix error with python multiplication across arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have obtained 3 lists/arrays in my python script and I am wondering why I am not able to multiply them to values successfully.

```
Array 1: [-0.01896408 -0.0191784  -0.01939271 ...  0.97766441  0.97745009
  0.97723578]
Array 2: [ 1.21527999  1.21302709  1.21077419 ... -0.69821075 -0.70046365
 -0.70271655]
Array 3: [-0.19631591 -0.1938487  -0.19138148 ...  0.72054634  0.72301355
  0.72548077]
```

These are the points I am multiplying it with:
`pointsArray = np.array([[103.890991,1.369125], [103.8892,1.368017], [103.8903,1.367166],[103.890221,1.367944] ])`

What I want to do is this:

```
transformPoint = array1[i]*pointsArray[0] + array2[i]*pointsArray[1]  + array3[i]*pointsArray[2]
 df["new_X"] = transformPoint[0]
 df["new Y"] = transformPoint[1]
```

where the pointsarray value is constant for every iteration in the loop and the arrays should iterate thru all values in them.

This is the error I am getting with the transform point calculation line:
`transformPoint = array1[i]*pointsArray[0] + array2[i]*pointsArray[1]  + array3[i]*pointsArray[2]`

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (28686,) (2,)
```

How do I fix this or how do I go about with doing this calculation?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't multiply together arrays of shapes (28686, ) and (2, ) as they are incompatible shapes. See more here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: reshape your array operands

Comment: `pointsArray[0]` is indeed of shape (2,). How do you expect it to be multiplied by `array1`? May you provide an example of result you are looking for?

Comment: what is `i` in your expression, if each of `array1`, `array2` etc. are lists? What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, what you want to do is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([-0.01896408, -0.0191784, -0.01939271, 0.97766441, 0.97745009, 0.97723578])
array2 = np.array([ 1.21527999, 1.21302709, 1.21077419, -0.69821075, -0.70046365, -0.70271655])
array3 = np.array([-0.19631591, -0.1938487, -0.19138148, 0.72054634, 0.72301355, 0.72548077])

pointsArray = np.array([[103.890991,1.369125], [103.8892,1.368017], [103.8903,1.367166],[103.890221,1.367944] ])

transformPoint = array1.reshape(-1, 1)*pointsArray[0].reshape(1,-1) + array2.reshape(-1, 1)*pointsArray[1].reshape(1,-1)  + array3.reshape(-1, 1)*pointsArray[2].reshape(1,-1)
print(transformPoint)

print(transformPoint.mean(axis=0))
```

The output will be:

```sh
[[103.88895009   1.36816305]
 [103.88895138   1.3681607 ]
 [103.88895475   1.36815838]
 [103.8917436    1.36848707]
 [103.89174489   1.36848472]
 [103.89174826   1.36848239]]

[103.89034883   1.36832272]
```

Let me know, if this is **NOT** what you wished to achieve, since your question does not explain your objective.

Comment: yep this works really well thank you! that's exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I have to post my comment like this:

As I understand it you try to multiply elements of the "pointsArray" with a scalar.
Have you tried printing

```
array1[i]
```

to see what it looks like? From the error I would guess that this is somehow not just a number, but the entire array. You could for example try to print

```
array[0][i]
```

to see if the output is the first number in array1.

Answer (score -1):

dot is used for matrix multiplication.
Try this:

```
matrix1.dot(matrix2)
```

A bit more clarity:
If you want to use *, convert both to numpy.matrix and then try.

Comment: There's no way a vector of shape (28686,) can be multiplied with `pointsArray` of shape (4,2)

Comment: Your answer is completely wrong.  `dot` is used for dot product.  The term "matrix multiplication" has a specific meaning, and the numpy `*` operator implements that meaning.  The original asker seems to want element-wise multiplication, which is neither of these.